# Open a link in new tab using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

*I have looked at many answers

[Selenium IDE:Opening in new tab and shift focus to new tab not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372921/selenium-ideopening-in-new-tab-and-shift-focus-to-new-tab-not-workinghttp://)

[How to open link in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273307/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab)  etc....
posted regarding this question but not even a single one is 100% relevant therefore, I am asking this again.*
I need to open three different links:
`google.com`
`yahoo.com`
`microsoft.com`
in three different tabs but under same window and I am using selenium IDE, I know, it is easier using WebDriver but unfortunately I am using IDE. If I use `Open` it just opens the next link in the same tab and when I use `OpenWindow` or `openWindowAndWait`, it just opens the new window which I do not want.

Can someone please help..

Answer (score 1):

There's no command within Selenium IDE which directly relates to Tabs, Selenium IDE is just not built to work with them. There's a post fro ma few years ago which references an answer from a selenium dev stating this ([Selenium IDE for Firefox Ctrl-Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550360/selenium-ide-for-firefox-ctrl-tab))

The only way to potentially get it working would be to use send Keys to simulate Ctrl+T to open a new tab. There's a post [here](http://selenium.10932.n7.nabble.com/Can-Selenium-IDE-open-a-new-tab-or-window-in-Firefox-td5858.html) which gives details on it.

Comment: tried it but did not work, dont know if I am doing it right. I just used the exactly same code. I am bit confused what should come in (here `<td>link=Home</td>`) this line `<td>keyPress</td>
<td>link=Home</td>
<td>t</td>`